# Get-Content cannot read from variable

Tags: powershell, variables

I have a couple of lines of PowerShell I'm writing for a script, I'm not understanding too well why this isn't functioning properly.

```
$addressList=Invoke-WebRequest "https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt" -OutFile "file" -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
(Get-Content $addressList) -join ","
```

I get the following error message;

```
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:14
+ (Get-Content $addressList) -join ","
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

If however I replace $addressList in the Get-Content line with the actual file .\filename.txt it works perfectly. Can anyone help me to get this working? rationale behind storing this in a variable is I'm going to run this in a PowerShell script via an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the data into a variable, don't use `-OutFile`.

Once you have the data in a variable, you no longer need `Get-Content` - you just need to split the resulting string into the individual addresses:

```
$addressList = Invoke-WebRequest "https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt" -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content

-split $addressList -join ','
```

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223994/45375), which fully addresses your problem, with a **general tip**:

It is often sufficient to use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) instead of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest), which simplifies things, because `Invoke-RestMethod` *directly* returns the data (no wrapper object whose `.Content` property must be accessed).

In your case, the solution can therefore be simplified to:

```
-split (
  Invoke-RestMethod https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt
) -join ','
```